# How to install this European Sauna Heater/Controller in Canada?

Tags: electrical, 240v, heater

I have recently purchased this 9KW European sauna heater:

[image: HUUM drop 9KW]

A similar question was asked in [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148516/can-this-european-sauna-heater-be-installed-in-the-us). I am looking for more specifics on how to connect the TECK cable from the breaker box into the main controller.

Here is the heater (5) and input connection diagram on the main controller:

[image]

Can this be wired in Canada/US where the TECK cable comming in from the breaker would have two hots, a neutral, and ground? If so, how (what connects where)? The breaker box would be wired with a 50A double pole breaker. The full manual for the main controller is [here](https://huum.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/UKU_User_Manual.pdf). The plan would be to also have the electrician add a disconnect unit as described [here](https://www.nootkasaunas.com/sauna-wiring-instructions/). Anything I'm missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In US/Canada, you would connect it according to the 230V diagram: L1/2/3 together to 1 hot , N to the other hot, ground to ground. The European neutral is basically the same as the 2nd hot in a double-pole 240V US/Canada circuit. This is based on the device not needing a *true* neutral but really just needing to have hot and neutral ~ 230V apart. Two things though to make 100% sure you are safe:

- Neutral != ground. That is extremely important here, because if you had the equivalent of a typical 3-wire dryer connection where neutral and ground are bonded, it would be potentially deadly here because it would put a *hot* wire on ground. To make sure check with a multimeter to make sure that when the device is not connected that you do *not* have any continuity between device N and ground and when the device is connected you should see ~ 240V device N and ground.
- GFCI - Absolutely 100% critical that this be on a double-pole GFCI breaker.

**But wait ! You can't do that!** One of the links said "As per the heater’s manual, this should NOT be a GFI breaker." and another link to the manual says "It is recommended to connect the unit to the mains without an earth-leakage circuit breaker."

Which means they are saying to **not** use a GFCI. But normal US/Canada code (and common sense) says **use a GFCI**. Those conflict. Unlike some alterations related to code, this is not approved by UL or ETL (unless I missed something...). They aren't even involved as this is designed for the European market (230V/400V). When approved by UL or ETL, manufacturer instructions different from the usual code are allowed.

So either install with a GFCI, *and run the risk of any warranty being invalidated due to not following directions*, or install without a GFCI and run the risk of fatal problems if there is ever a serious malfunction. **Don't do that!**

Comment: Thanks you - I'm a bit confused. I think you are saying that for the TECK cable I would connect one hot to L1, one to L2, neutral to N, and ground to ground. Do I just leave L3 unused? Isn't the voltage between hot and neutral going to be 120V in this case? Thanks again!

Comment: @alexvpickering it's all confusing. The upshot is that neutral is an arbitrary designation... they're all hot wires, we just picked one and called it neutral.  However the way we picked it, our neutral is useless to a European appliance.

Comment: One hot from panel to l1 l2 l3 combined. Other hot from panel to N. Ground to ground. Neutral from panel **not used**.

Comment: This answer is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Devices must be installed in accordance with manufacturer instructions. The instructions do not say it can be hooked up to US/CA style split-phase 240V power, so it can’t be. End of story.

Comment: Connecting one hot to the L1/L2/L3 input and the other hot to N would work (produce the expected power) but could be dangerous - parts normally at 0V from ground (with Euro style supply) will now be 120V from ground. Likely at *all* times because the device likely doesn’t switch neutral.

Comment: Connecting one US/CA hot to L1/L2/L3 and neutral to N would be safer but will result in only ~1/4 the rated power output. And the control electronics might not function on 120V.

Comment: Thank you @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact for the clarification/edit - that makes sense to me. Do I need to do anything special to combine L1/L2/L3 them or since they are all connected can 1 hot just go to e.g. L2?

Comment: The diagram shows L1/L2/L3 together to a hot wire in one of the diagrams for 230V. I don't know if they have something special for that or if it is "wire nut". Presumably each of L1/L2/L3 powers a separate heating element, in which case only connecting to L2 would only get you 1/3 of the power/heat. But that is just a guess.

Comment: @nobody European appliances, if properly designed and built, are not *inherently* unsafe or inappropriate for use in the US/Canada. If they don't have a US/Canada-compatible certification (typically UL or ETL) then they would need approval from the AHJ. Who might outright reject, or might look at it and say "Yeah, that's fine but install according to code" - meaning "GFCI, proper wire sizes, etc." My end point is that a device that in the US/Canada clearly *requires* GFCI that says *don't use GFCI* has a major problem that can't be overcome by translation of "hot wires", etc.

Comment: As far as "can it be used with US/Canada split phase power" - aside from any regulatory issues, it comes down to design. Using a simple light fixture as an example, there is a normal configuration that the outer ring of a bulb socket is tied to neutral. **Specifically neutral** and not "something other than one of the hots" because to provide safety it needs to be effectively near ground. But the N here, while *conceptually* neutral in that it is the return for all the L* hot wires, if well designed will not be exposed in any way to users any more than the L* hot wires and if properly kept

Comment: away from metal parts of the case, ground, etc. is 100% perfectly safe to be connected to "the other US/Canada 240V hot" instead of to neutral. We don't know that for sure, but it seems quite plausible. The GFCI problem, on the other hand, can't be so easily worked around.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- can you provide a citation for GFCI being required for sauna heaters?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel A little searching seems to find that there may not be any strict rules/actual code requirement. But if it is a sauna with water (there are apparently dry and wet, and the linked controller manual does reference a water tank/vaporiser) then GFCI seems to be an *extremely* logical safety item.